# I've inherited an older web forms site code and cannot figure out what is wrong with it

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a standard default.aspx page with code.  In the page there is 
      `<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="_lnkDownload">Dowload</asp:LinkButton>`

but the code behind does not recognize the button, says it cannot resolve symbol.  This is just one example of a hundred different controls that are not recognized in the code behind.  If more information is needed please let me know.

Comment: Is it a top level control? It really sounds like it's part of e.g. a `asp:Repeater`, `asp:GridView` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

OK, what happened was the designer.cs file was out of sync with the aspx page.  I deleted those files and for each aspx file I right-clicked and selected convert to web application which regenerated the designer file.